# Flutter: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to

```
launch("tel://21213123123")
```

But, I'm getting the following error!

```
PlatformException (PlatformException(error, Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?, null))
```

in this file

```
message_codecs.dart
```

Here is my error log

```
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher(26131): Failed to handle method call
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher(26131): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher(26131):     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:672)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher(26131):     at android.app.ContextImpl.startActivity(ContextImpl.java:659)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher(26131):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.startActivity(ContextWrapper.java:331)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher(26131):     at io.flutter.plugins.urllauncher.UrlLauncherPlugin.onMethodCall(UrlLauncherPlugin.java:61)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher(26131):     at io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:200)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher(26131):     at io.flutter.view.FlutterNativeView.handlePlatformMessage(FlutterNativeView.java:163)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher(26131):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher(26131):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:323)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher(26131):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher(26131):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5468)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher(26131):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher(26131):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
E/MethodChannel#plugins.flutter.io/url_launcher(26131):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:671)
```

Comment: They're using the `url_launcher` package which lets you `launch` a url such as a phone number to launch the device's default phone app. @Vishnu Maheswaran K can you provide the code where you're using the `launch` method?

Answer (score 5):

Just had the same problem with the new Version of the urlLauncher 4.0.2 Plugin

I downgraded to 3.0.3 and everything worked fine so there might be a bug inside the repository.

pubspec.yaml

```
 url_launcher: 3.0.3
```

Sample Code (taken from the git repo but it works for me with 3.0.3)

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/url_launcher

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(Scaffold(
    body: Center(
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: _launchURL,
        child: Text('Show Flutter homepage'),
      ),
    ),
  ));
}

_launchURL() async {
  const url = 'https://flutter.io';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    throw 'Could not launch $url';
  }
}
```

For all avaiable versions of the Plugin see here.
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/url_launcher#-changelog-tab-

Comment: @ManuelBechmann thank you! this solve the problem, hope they solve it for newer versions aswell